How to configure multiple Sybase datasources in Spring Boot?
I am trying to configure multiple Sybase datasources in my Spring Boot application. When I only had one datasource, everything worked out of the box, but I can't seem to add another one. I have two Sybase databases with the following connection details:
Single Datasource Configuration (Worked Fine):
spring:
  datasource:
    sybase:
      url: host
      username: example_user1
      password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      driver-class-name: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
      hikari:
        auto-commit: false
        minimum-idle: 1
        maximum-pool-size: 10
        pool-name: pool

This way, I didn't have to set up anything special in my application to make it work besides the repository and the usual stuff.
Attempted Multiple Datasource Configuration (Not Working):
spring:
  datasource:
    sybase:
      database1:
        url: host1
        username: example_user1
        password: ${DB1_PASSWORD}
        driver-class-name: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
      database2:
        url: host2
        username: example_user2
        password: ${DB2_PASSWORD}
        driver-class-name: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver


Including datasource configuration where I initialize them as beans and templates:
@Configuration
class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = ["dataSource1"])
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sybase.dataSource1")
    @Primary
    fun db1DataSource(): DataSource {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build()
    }

        @Bean(name = ["db1JdbcTemplate"])
    fun db1JdbcTemplate(
        @Qualifier("dataSource1") dataSource1: DataSource?,
    ): JdbcTemplate {
        return JdbcTemplate(dataSource1!!)
    }
[...]


update  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sybase.dataSource1") to
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.sybase.database1").
basically typo dataSource1 -> database1
